# regex searching for a backslash

Tags: php, regex, escaping

why is it that in searching for a backslash in a regex you need to escape the backslash 4 times?

Example:

```
$pattern = '/\\\\/';
$string = 'to\m';
preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => \
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are two levels of parsing being done, once by PHP, and a second time by the regular expression engine:

1. The intended target: `\`
2. Well I need to put that in a string without it escaping the character after it: `"\\"`, PHP sees `\`
3. Now I need to feed that into a regex: `"\\\\"` PHP sees `\\`, regex engine sees `\`

The function [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) will remove a layer of confusion for you by escaping all regular expression metacharacters for you. eg:

```
$foo = preg_quote("c:\\some\\path\\or_whatever");
preg_match("/$foo/", $bar);
```

###edit

You seem to be thinking of this as "units of `\\`", which doesn't seem like an accurate depiction of what is happening. For a better example let's use a different character that is also significant in both PHP and regular expressions, `$`.

1. Intended target: `$`
2. Escaping for a PHP string: `"\$"`, the literal string seen by PHP is `$`
3. Escaping for a PHP string to be interpreted as a literal `$` in a regular expression:
   `"\\\$"`, PHP sees the literal string `\$`, the regular expression sees the literal string `$`

Illustrated with different styles of braces representing different levels of escaping:

```
0: $     $
1: \$    [\$]
2: \\\\  [{\\}{\$}]

0: \     \
1: \\    [\\]
2: \\\\  [{\\}{\\}]

0: \\server\$c\Windows
1: [\\][\\]server[\\][\$]c[\\]Windows
2: [{\\}{\\}][{\\}{\\}]server[{\\}{\\}][{\\}{\$}]c[{\\}{\\}]Windows
```

Which also illustrates why dealing with Windows paths sucks butts.

Comment: So the first \\ is for PHP escaping (so php sees \) and the second \\ is for the regex escaping (so the regex engine sees \)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the backslash has a special meaning in both a php string and a regular expression, so you must escape it twice:

To match a single backslash, the pure regex should be:

```
/\\/
```

If it was:

```
/\/
```

, the backslash would be escaping the forward slash, leading to an invalid regex matching a single forward slash, but missing it's ending slash.

Then, this pure regex is put into a php string, and each backslash is again escaped:

```
'/\\\\/'
```

Comment: Hmmm okkkkkkkkkk. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Because a backslash is a special character, you need to escape it twice. So \\ for the first backslash, and \\ for the second.